# Catching Your Focus

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This may need some attention to get it, or it may be too easy for the community.

> My prefix sins, refutes, and help you see,
>
> My infix you won't bother to count.
>
> My suffix tells you if something's good or bad,
>
> And you'll get it if you do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Concentrate

My prefix sins, refutes, and help you see,

> **Con** - which can mean *to deceive or trick someone* (sins), *an argument against something* (refutes) or *to study attentively* (helps you to see).

My infix you won't bother to count.

> **Cent** - a monetary unit in various countries, equal to one hundredth of a dollar, euro, or other decimal currency unit, a very small value.

My suffix tells you if something's good or bad,

> **Rate** - which means to *assign a standard or value to something according to a particular scale.*

And you'll get it if you do it!

> **Concentrate** - a substance made by removing or reducing the diluting agent, made by concentrating.

Comment: answer correct, +1 + accept! Great job!